# Insert value to Data Grid without Showing it

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have `PictureBox` and i want the `PictureBox` to be saved at my `DataTable` but without showing it to my `DataGrid`.

How do i do it ?

Thanks

Comment: You don't save a PictureBox in a database, you save the Image bytes. If you don't want the bytes to be shown as an Image in a DataGridView, exclude the Image Column from the query or don't add that Column to the DataGridView in the designer. You can also hide the Column and show it again if you change your mind :)

Comment: Also: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls.

Comment: thank you brother! sorry for calling that, didnt know.